# Get records with no related data using activerecord and RoR3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am making `scopes` for a model that looks something like this:

```
class PressRelease < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :publications
end
```

What I want to get is all `press_releases` that does not have `publications`, but from a `scope` method, so it can be chained with other scopes. Any ideas?

Thanks!

NOTE: I know that there are methods like `present?` or `any?` and so on, but these methods does not return an `ActiveRecord::Relation` as scope does.

NOTE: I am using RoR 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid `eager_loading` if you do not need it (it adds overhead). Also, there is no need for subselect statements.

```
scope :without_publications, -> { joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN publications ON publications.press_release_id = press_releases.id").where(publications: { id: nil }) }
```

#### Explanation and response to comments

My initial thoughts about eager loading overhead is that ActiveRecord would instantiate all the child records (publications) for each press release. Then I realized that the query will never return press release records with publications. So that is a moot point.

There are some points and observations to be made about the way ActiveRecord works. Some things I had previously learned from experience, and some things I learned exploring your question.

The query from `includes(:publications).where(publications: {id: nil})` is actually different from my example. It will return all columns from the `publications` table in addition to the columns from `press_releases`. The publication columns are completely unnecessary because they will always be null. However, both queries ultimately result in the same set of `PressRelease` objects.

With the includes method, if you add any sort of limit, for example chaining `.first`, `.last` or `.limit()`, then ActiveRecord (4.2.4) will resort to executing two queries. The first query returns IDs, and the second query uses those IDs to get results. Using the SQL snippet method, ActiveRecord is able to use just one query. Here is an example of this from one of my applications:

```
Profile.includes(:positions).where(positions: { id: nil }).limit(5)
# SQL (0.8ms)  SELECT  DISTINCT "profiles"."id" FROM "profiles" LEFT OUTER JOIN "positions" ON "positions"."profile_id" = "profiles"."id" WHERE "positions"."id" IS NULL LIMIT 5
# SQL (0.8ms)  SELECT "profiles"."id" AS t0_r0, ..., "positions"."end_year" AS t1_r11 FROM "profiles" LEFT OUTER JOIN "positions" ON "positions"."profile_id" = "profiles"."id" # WHERE "positions"."id" IS NULL AND "profiles"."id" IN (107, 24, 7, 78, 89)

Profile.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN positions ON positions.profile_id = profiles.id").where(positions: { id: nil }).limit(5)
# Profile Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "profiles".* FROM "profiles" LEFT OUTER JOIN positions ON positions.profile_id = profiles.id WHERE "positions"."id" IS NULL LIMIT 5
```

#### Most importantly

`eager_loading` and `includes` were not intended to solve the problem at hand. And for this particular case I think you are much more aware of what is needed than ActiveRecord is. You can therefore make better decisions about how to structure the query.

Comment: This is the best response, as it covers optimization of time. However, why can I not use `includes(:publications).where(publications: {id: nil})` instead? It generates the same SQL query, and is more ruby-like. I also checked load time of both methods in production console and they are alike. I understand that `includes` method does `eager loading`. Can you provide a resource of eagerload overhead please ? Thanks again :)

Comment: @DanielBatalla My response became very lengthy, so I added it to my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

you can de the following in your `PressRelease`:

```
scope :your_scope, -> { where('id NOT IN(select press_release_id from publications)') }
```

this will return all PressRelease record without publications.

Answer (score 0):

Couple ways to do this, first one requires two db queries:

```
PressRelease.where.not(id: Publications.uniq.pluck(:press_release_id))
```

or if you don't want to hardcode association foreign key:

```
PressRelease.where.not(id: PressRelease.uniq.joins(:publications).pluck(:id))
```

Another one is to do a left join and pick those without associated elements - you get a relation object, but it will be tricky to work with it as it already has a join on it:

```
PressRelease.eager_load(:publications).where(publications: {id: nil})
```

Another one is to use counter_cache feature. You will need to add `publication_count` column to your `press_releases` table.

```
class Publications < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :presss_release, counter_cache: true
end
```

Rails will keep this column in sync with a number of records associated to given mode, so then you can simply do:

```
PressRelease.where(publications_count: [nil, 0])
```

Comment: @DanielBatalla if you need a solution for a specific version of Rails (especially an older version) then you should state so in your question.